# Total price hook or variable in Woocommerce Email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I add total price in Email order heading like {order_number}?

[Email Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIgLs.jpg)

[Customer Email Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpGHw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [woocommerce_email_heading_(id)](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_email_heading_(id)) filter to do that.

Here `(id)` is email template id e.g.: `new_order`, `customer_processing_order`, etc

This filter provides 3 `@param`
1: formatted title
2. order object
3. email object

you can get the total price from the order object and then replace it with your placeholder.

**Note:** Make sure you validate the order object with `is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' )` then after applying you replace the logic.